# BootstrapVue table data not sortable using Vuex getter

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue, state-management

Hey there short question I do use a BootstrapVue table and the data it shows is provided by a vuex getter invoked at the mounted hook.
Why is it not possible to use the standard sort option provided by the component (b-table) itself?
If I do the same in a method with a axios.get it works perfectly. I think it has to do with vuex state management but I'm not sure.

Comment: Solved it by myself. Changed from this.$store.getters.getterName to mapGetters.
Think the problem was my modularization of the application and namespaced store modules.